# Why is the response available in a service but in the component is undefined?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, observable

I have a service and a component which uses the service.The issue is that in a service I can read the response which is as JSON object. But in the Component, I get the following: `res: undefined`.

**service:**

```
constructor(
    private http: Http,
    private fbuilder: FormBuilder,
    private user: UserService
) {}
login(uname:string, pass:string): Observable<any> {

    let headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Username':uname,
        'Password':pass
    });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let data = {};
    var Observable = this.http.post( url, data, options )
    .map(res => {
        res.json();
    })
    .catch( (error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error') );
    return Observable;
}
```

**component:**

```
constructor(
    private http: Http,
    private fbuilder: FormBuilder,
    private user: UserService
) {}
loginUser(uname: string, pass: string) {
    this.user.login(uname, pass).subscribe(
        res => {
            console.log('res: ' + JSON.stringify(res));
        },
        err => {
            this.errorMessage = err;
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your problem is with this code:

```
.map(res => {
    res.json();
})
```

You're not returning the result of `res.json`. You just need to add the `return` statement, like so:

```
.map(res => {
    return res.json();
})
```

You could also just remove the `{}` pair, like so:

```
.map(res => res.json())
```

Comment: Ohhh. My Bad. You're right! Had the same issue before and found out that I had to return the `res.json()`. Issues solved. And yes, removing the `{}` would save some code, but I want to print out the the res. in the `console`.